# объект 'Command' не имеет атрибута 'has_permissions'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image: Ошибка вызвана проблемой в команде clear]

Ошибка вызвана проблемой в команде clear.
Но сверху , используется такой же атрибут

```
#Command Mute
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'muted')
    await member.add_roles( mute_role)
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} замучен за нарушение правил')
#Command clear
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=1):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
```

Comment: Приведите ошибку в текстовом виде и дайте нормальный заголовок

Comment: Во-первых, что такое commands, а во-вторых, приведите код достаточно полный для воспроизведения проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Установите версию 1.3.4

```
pip install discord.py==1.3.4
```